# image processing / computer vision - body part recognition - posture ( standing/ sitting) - supervised learning

Tags: node.js, image-processing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I'm after advice from the image processing / computer vision experts here. Trying to develop a robust, scaled algorithm to extract dimensions of a person's body. For example, his upper-body width.

**problems**:

- images without faces
- person sitting
- multiple faces
- person is holding something , thus covering part of his body

ways of doing this: 
* haar  - unsupervised , a lot of training date of different body parts and hope for the best.
* HOG   - 1. face detection -> afterwards using HOG and assumptions along the way with different filters

**Note**: all images will be scaled to the same size.

Obviously computation time for the second approach MIGHT be more demanding (doubtful though) 
but for the 1st method, training is almost impossible and would take much more time..

P.S.
I know there's a paper about using pedestrian data.. but that would work for full body + standing, not for sitting.

I'm open to hearing all your ideas..ask away if you have anything to add.

Implementation would be done, hopefully via `node.js`

Thank you

Comment: i haven't had any experience with image processing, but this task looks extremely difficult also there aren't any native image processing modules in node.js so you might want to try writing this in C++ as an addon , requiring some kind of image processing libraries and work with nodejs javascript to expose the API.

Comment: @Phoenix: tnx for the comment, true. It is difficult. There are libs for node.js that does face detection , HOG, etc.. there's also an openCV module. I agree with everything you wrote, hoping to hear some expert's advice :)

Answer (score 0):

DPM is widely used in computer vision for object detection and it tends to work in the case of occlusion and also when only part of an object is present in the image. The grammar model for humans is very good and has state of the art results on standard datasets. It takes around a second to perform detection on a single image, its matlab code, so its expected to be slow.

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rbg/latent/